# Class 'Drupal\Component\Utility\XSS' not found (Drupal 8)

Tags: php, drupal, xss, drupal-8

In a working Drupal 8 site in THEME.theme I have

```
function fcx_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['get']['vguid'] = \Drupal\Component\Utility\XSS::filter($_GET['vguid']);
}

function fcx_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['get']['vguid'] = \Drupal\Component\Utility\XSS::filter($_GET['vguid']);
}
```

I have verified that the file core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Xss.php exists with permissions 0664 and declares class XSS.  In that file the method is declared `public static function filter(`...

When accessing pages which reference `get.vguid` I get error `Class 'Drupal\Component\Utility\XSS' not found`

I have no idea what further steps I should take. Is the call incorrect?  Searching on it seems to suggest the usage is correct...

Comment: Could be casing on the classname `\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss`

Comment: You rock!  Please add as answer!

Comment: np and thanks, easily done, I do it all the time :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a quick look on the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.php/class/Xss/8.2.x) the class name is Xss:

```
namespace Drupal\Component\Utility;

class Xss {}
```

So call it like:

`\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss`